# Compile entire C project instead of few files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, terminal

I have an entire library made in C. It has almost 10 folders with a lot of files.

I have created a filename.c file in root folder and trying to compile it in mac using `gcc test.c -o test` however its not including header files. Generally I have to add all the header files `gcc test.c libaudio.c -o test`

How can I compile entire project instead of just one file.

Comment: Your use of the term "header file" to describe something called "libaudio.c" confuses me.

Comment: Have you looked into the features for handling multiple files as offered by the `make` tool?

Comment: @Yunnosch my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Makefile`.  `make` the utility the reads the configuration within the `Makefile` will automate the running of the individual commands, such that you only need to name the item you wish to be rebuilt.

```
make myprogram
```

And make will use the dependency information stored in the `Makefile`'s rules to determine what other elements are "out of date", rebuilding those and assembling them into `myprogram`.

[This is a decent "first time" tutorial for "make".](http://www.firmcodes.com/linux/write-first-makefile-c-source-code-linux-tutorial/)

[Here is the full blown documentation for "make"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Once you master the concepts within make, you can then use other tools that make maintaining `Makefiles` either easier, more portable, or both.

Some tools that improve upon "make" include "cmake", "automake", "the autotools collection", "scons", "waf", "rake", "doit", "ninja", "tup", "redo", and "sake".  There are more, and some are programming language specific, or limited to a particular enviornment.

The reason I recommend "make" over the others is because "make" is a baseline that will always be present, and the features in the other tools are often not understood or recognized to be needed until you get enough experience with "make".

Comment: agree on Make, if I try to compile someone else's project and it uses ninja or cmake... it better "just work" because I really don't have the patience to learn someone else's build system just to try it out

Answer (score 4):

Makefiles will solve your problem. You can create your own rules to clear the project (remove the generated files), build the project indicating where is your compiler (compile the source files located in some specific path, extension, etc), set the output path and so on, without typing a large compilation order.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Edit: There you will be able to find how to add shared, static or raw libraries to your proyect through makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the concept of project is not part of the language, it depends generally of the tools / platform / library you have to build.

On Linux based platforms, you may have a `makefile` describing the project, or the library may have a `cmake` script.

You should be able to find the build instructions in you library documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend the make approach as it is scalable.

If you really only have a couple of files, gcc will accept multiple .c files on the command line and link them all to generate one executable.